# List file names during run time from App script HTML

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-apps-script

I have created an app script to get list of all files available in Gdrive. While executing I m unable to pass the file names which are generated during the execution to  tag.
My goal is to list the file names which are generated to be populated in HTML

**Code.gs**

```
var gSheetName;
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1XyZ2m_knnyM7cLN-DtLcHyLX0pKOt5uASCcV8');
var sheets= sheet.getSheetByName('FileList');
var Fname, CountofFiles;

var sessionuser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('params').evaluate();
}


function Start() {

try {
  gSheetName=sheet.getId();
  listFolders(DriveApp.getRootFolder());
  return Fname;
}


catch(error) { return error.toString();}
}

function listFolders(folder) {

  var folder = folder || DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  var data;

  while ( files.hasNext() ) {
    var file1 = files.next();
    var file1 = file1.getId();
    var file=DriveApp.getFileById(file1);
    var value = Math.floor((file.getLastUpdated()-file.getDateCreated())/(24*3600*1000));
    var value1;
    var emailid = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    Fname = file.getName(); //I want to list this file name in HTML one by one
    fileList(Fname);

    data = [
      file.getName(),
      file.getDateCreated(),
      file.getLastUpdated(),
      folder.getName(),
      folder.getId(),
      file.getSize()
    ];

    sheets.appendRow(data);
    data=[];
  }

  var subfolders = folder.getFolders();
  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
    listFolders(subfolders.next());
  }
}

function fileList(fileName) {
  var Fname1 = Fname;
  return Fname1;
  }
```

**params.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">

  </head>
  <body>
          <form id="myForm">
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(execute).Start();Showhide();">
              <i class="material-icons left">cloud</i> Execute
              </a>
          </form>


<div id="output" style="display:none">
  <p>Please wait while we are extracting records...</p>
  <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40/giphy.gif">
</div>
<div id="Flist"></div>

<script>
function execute(status) {
    document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('Flist').innerHTML = execute();
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Completed';
}
function Showhide() {
  var x = document.getElementById("output");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
</script>
```

I Need to display list of files which are generated by "Fname = file.getName();" this is where the file names are stored to the variable Fname. Is there a way i can populate these file names in HTML. I tried logging the records which is giving me the names in log but unfortunately i m unable to list in HTML  tag. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Store them on a spreadsheet, or cache first and the pass them to html later.  If you initiate the search with google.script.run the you can use withSuccessHandler to get the files from the temporary storage and display them on the dialog or web app.  But there's probably going to be a lot of them  so you may run into time outs of data size limits.

Comment: @Cooper storing them in a sheet and retriving is possible but i need to be shown the file name as like a flash news, not the entire content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use [google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#success_handlers) and the server function returns a value, the API passes the value to the new function as a parameter.

Which means when you call `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(execute).Start()`, the return value of your `Start()` will be passed as an argument in your `execute()`.

I noticed that you are trying to call your execute() to get your `Flist` here:

```
function execute(status) {
    document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('Flist').innerHTML = execute();
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Completed';
}
```

---

### Sample Code Modification:

(code.gs - modified part only)

```
var Fname = [], CountofFiles;

function Start() {

  try {
    gSheetName=sheet.getId();
    //Clear sheet
    sheets.clear();
    listFolders(DriveApp.getRootFolder());
    return Fname;
  }
  catch(error) { return error.toString();}
}

function listFolders(folder) {

  var folder = folder || DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  var data;

  while ( files.hasNext() ) {
    var file1 = files.next();
    var file1 = file1.getId();
    var file=DriveApp.getFileById(file1);
    var value = Math.floor((file.getLastUpdated()-file.getDateCreated())/(24*3600*1000));
    var value1;
    var emailid = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    //var fileFname = file.getName(); //I want to list this file name in HTML one by one
    //fileList(file.getName());
    Fname.push(file.getName());

    data = [
      file.getName(),
      file.getDateCreated(),
      file.getLastUpdated(),
      folder.getName(),
      folder.getId(),
      file.getSize()
    ];

    sheets.appendRow(data);
    data=[];
  }

  var subfolders = folder.getFolders();
  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
    listFolders(subfolders.next());
  }
}
```

(params.html - modified part only)

```
function execute(status) {
  document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';    
  document.getElementById('Flist').innerHTML = status;
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Completed';
}
```

### Changes done:

1. Clear `FileList` sheet every time you click `Execute` in your html page
2. I changed `Fname` to an array and push all file names found.
3. The array of file names returned by  `Start()` will be passed as argument in your `execute(status)` hence you can access that in your `status` variable.

### Output:

[image]

Comment: In this way i will get all the file name listed only after completing the task right?. But i need file names to be running so that the user can see that the code is running and what are all the file names are processed

Comment: You'r code works as you said but i need to display the file names like a flash news. for that do we need to use Ajax?

Comment: Sorry, I did not fully understand your goal. You want to display the file name that was being read/append in the sheets to your html one at a time? when listFolders() is running? If yes, then it might be impossible to do so, as what I mentioned in the answer, when you use google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function) the return value of your apps script function will be passed as argument in your handler function. This means that your apps script function was already executed. You cannot return a value  during runtime of your listFolders()

Comment: yes ron that's what i want but thanks for the alternative solution.